# How to create a data-driven list of lists in R

Tags: r, list

The code below does exactly what I need, but there has to be a better way to do this.  I need to create a list of lists with titles so that I can subset like this: `position.list[["a.com"]]`

There has to be a way to do this more efficiently, as what I have below is pretty horrendous.  I saw several similar topics, but none seemed to do exactly what I need... I apologize if this has been answered before.

```
website.vec <- c("a.com", "b.com", "c.com")
position.list <- vector(len = length(website.vec))
position.list <- setNames(as.list(position.list), website.vec)
for (i in 1:length(position.list)) {
  position.list[[i]] <- list()
}
```

Comment: ah the uppercase "R" threw me off...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

```
setNames(replicate(length(website.vec), list(), simplify=FALSE), website.vec)
```

Option 2:

```
lapply(setNames(nm=website.vec), function(x) list())
```

Comment: i tried one just like the `lapply()` method, but without `setNames`.  Thanks!

Comment: just ran a couple tests.  looks like the the `lapply()` method is a bit faster (not that it matters for me, as `website.vec` will likely be no more than 100 elements long...)

Comment: the names in the results of `lapply` are the names of `lapply`'s main argument.